# What is the purpose of emedding a struct in a field (golang)?

Tags: go

Based on the below sample it seems that the point of "embedding an struct in a field" is to break Go's "promotion" mechanism. Why would you want to do this?

```
type obj1 struct {
    obj2
}

type obj1Selector struct {
    selector obj2
}

type obj2 struct {
}

func (o obj2) printTest() {
    fmt.Println("obj2")
}

func main() {
    o := obj1{}
    o.printTest() //fine

    oSelector := obj1Selector{}
    oSelector.selector.printTest() //fine
    oSelector.printTest() //not fine
```

Comment: Everytime you use `this`, a kitten dies.  Follow [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) guidelines, and give it a proper name.  For example: 
`func (o obj2) printTest() ...`

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking or how it relates at all to the "go/types" package (which you're not using) . What do you expect to happen here?

Comment: I fixed the this. Please stop hurting animals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not aliasing anything and selectors refer to the set of things that can be referenced on a type using dot notation. You're using a concept called embedding, `obj1` embeds `obj2`. `obj1Selector` has a single field called `selector` of type `obj2`. And alias would look like this; `type obj3 obj2` which declares `obj3` as an alias for `obj2`.

It breaks Go's promotion mechanism? Sorry but your whole idea of how this works is off basis. `obj1Selector` does not embed the type `obj2` and therefor has no field/methods from `obj2` 'promoted', `obj1` embeds `obj2` and therefor has it's fields/methods 'promoted'. `obj1Selector` does not implement that interface, `obj1Selector.selector` does.

Why would I want to embed? Well it's somewhat equivalent to inheritance or at least provides a similar feature set when developing in Go. Perhaps I have a number of records in a data store that all share 10 common fields and then have another 10 fields that depend on which table they came off of. Just as I'd use inheritance to reduce duplication in typical OO languages like C++, C# or Java I would use embedding in Go. In my opinion that is the main use case for it. It's sort of a weird mix of composition and inheritance. You're composing on object of others (the ones you're embedding) but since the embedded types methods/fields are promoted to the embedors scope it functions a lot like if the embedor inherited from the embedded type. Hope that gives some clarification as to what you're dealing with here... You haven't really posed a question that can be answered but there isn't space in the comments for such a lengthy explanation of the features/concepts you're using your sample code.

Comment: Your answer help me understand that I'm not creating an alias, but I still don't know why you would ever "embed the type in a field" like you said. Like you said wouldn't that be mixing "inheritance" and composition is a very confusing way in a single type?

Comment: @Charlie it may seem a bit confusing coming from a language where those two concepts are different but it's pretty intuitive once you start using it. If you want an inheritance hierarchy like you'd make using parent and child classes in typical OO languages you instead embed the base type in others to achieve the same functionality. There are some subtleties to the way it works but it's probably easiest to begin looking at it as being equivalent to inheritance.

Comment: Your answer didn't answer my question but I appreciate you helping my say it more clearly. Please read my refined question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704522/why-would-you-want-to-use-composition-in-golang