# Why would you want to use composition in golang?

Tags: go

In the following code I show what I think is the difference between embedding (where methods get promoted) and composition (where methods are not promoted) in golang.

Why would you ever want to use composition in golang?

```
type obj1Inherited struct {
    obj2
}

type obj1Composed struct {
    someobj obj2
}

type obj2 struct {
}

func (o obj2) printTest() {
    fmt.Println("obj2")
}

func main() {
    o := obj1Inherited{}
    o.printTest() //fine - printTest is promoted

    obj1Composed := obj1Composed{}
    obj1Composed.someobj.printTest() //fine because I'm using the composed obj
    obj1Composed.printTest() //not fine - printTest is NOT promoted
```

Comment: Can someone please explain why this was down voted? I've asked this same question 3 different ways now on SO and every time it's not answered and there's no helpful comments.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is worth going over the section on Embedding in [Effective Go](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#embedding).

A common example is having a struct/map with a Mutex.

```
type SafeStruct struct {
    SomeField string 
    *sync.Mutex
}
```

It is much easier to type

```
safe := SafeStruct{SomeField: "init value"}

safe.Lock()
defer safe.Unlock()
safe.SomeField = "new value"
```

than having to either write appropriate wrapper functions (which are repetitive) or have the stutter of

```
safe.mutex.Unlock()
```

when the only thing you would ever do with the mutex field is access the methods (`Lock()` and `Unlock()` in this case)

This becomes even more helpful when you are trying to use multiple functions on the embedded field (that implemement an interface like `io.ReadWriter`).

Comment: I simplified the question. It has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: Also for what's it worth - I've seen far "stupider" questions on SO for more established languages that are still at least answered and not heavily downvoted. This has made a strong impression on me that the go community doesn't want to help newcomers.

Comment: @Charlie, I'm sorry you feel that way. I didn't think your question was "stupid" or downvote-worthy. The SO Go community seems different than on the Golang Forum or Slack Channel or Go-Nuts mailing list.  A question about why/style might get a better response there.  Hopefully my answer helped you out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mutex case - that makes sense but seem like an edge case. As for the something like io.ReadWriter I thought that best practice would be "decorate" in which case you would want to promote methods so you could call something like o.save() which would then be implemented using something like io.Write(). Any thoughts on that? https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/09/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html

Comment: I've had to use the mutex for a map that would be accessed by multiple goroutines. Embedding isn't used that often, but can be really handy like [in bufio.ReadWriter](https://golang.org/src/bufio/bufio.go?s=17449:17493#L712)

Comment: @Charlie, on a client/server I'm developing, I have a limited struct in a library, then I extend it differently on the client/server. It's proven extremely useful when working with similar data or structs that embed the same data.

Comment: @user161778 that makes sense but that's an example of embedding NOT composition.

Comment: @user161778 it wasn't unclear - I understand the value of embedding - it's the closest thing go has to "inheritance." But this question is about composition where you intentionally prevent methods from being "promoted." Is that what you're doing? If so I'd love to see the code if you're willing to share :)

Comment: @Charlie, I'm a bit confused on your wording. Now reading your question carefully "Why would you want to use *composition*?", a couple simple answers are: Clarity (you can name the field) and functionality (other structs may share conflicting methods/fields, and you want to include them). I'll see if I can write a full answer. The accepted answer confused me to the scope of the question because it's about embedding :).

Comment: @Charlie embedding is a helpful wrapper of composition.  Composition is including the functionality/fields of smaller pieces in a larger vs inheritance, which is getting the functionality/fields by a relation to another class/object.

Answer (score 0):

One more point I want to cover for first case in your example.
If `obj1Inherited` and `obj2` have a same name method then that method call (from `obj1Inherited` instance) will always execute `obj1Inherited` method.

To call `obj2` method you can use the other approach of not promoting

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer original question - sometimes people use "composition" instead of embedding to hide functionality of embedded struct. Not a great use case - but people prefer it sometimes.

```golang
type Obj1composed struct {
  notExportedObj1 obj1
}

func NewObj1Composed(someParam Params) Obj1composed {
...
}

func (o Obj1Composed) Print() {
  // Some heavy calculations here. Make Dozens of API calls
  // print some data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Golang, there are 3 types of `embed`

- struct embed in struct
- interface embed in interface
- interface embed in struct

In detail you can refer to this post: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2020/embedding-in-go-part-1-structs-in-structs/